# Ошибка в чтении до пробела

Tags: c#

Считал текст из файла построчно. Пытаюсь в новый массив считать отдельную строку до пробела

```
    StreamReader f = new StreamReader(@"kod.txt");
    string[] a = f.ReadToEnd().Split('\r');
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
      string[] word = new string[a[i].Length];              //  получаем массив в котором будут все символы выбранной строки
      for (int j = 0; j < a[j].Length; j++)
      {
        word[j] = a[i].Split(' ');
      }
```

Возникает ошибка не удается преобразовать string[] в string. Все же верно, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

> Все же верно

Неверно. Подумайте, что находится слева и справа от знака `=` в строке

```
word[j] = a[i].Split(' ');
```

не говоря уже о мелочах типа `j < a[j].Length;`.

---

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("kod.txt"))
{
  string[] words = line.Split(' ');
  Console.WriteLine(words[0]);
}
```